3rd party widget not showing properly on front-end
I've build a vacation rental website for a client who is using Lodgify for their rentals. It's a simple one-page website, build with Elementor. Link to website
There are 3 rental listings, and each one has its own unique booking widget (HTML codes provided from Lodgify's website builder). Now the strange thing that's happening is that the widgets show up perfectly on the back-end, but 1 and sometimes 2 of them are not visible on the front-end.
The errors I see are:

Source map error: Error: request failed with status 403 Resource URL: https://app.lodgify.com/book-now-box/stable/renderBookNowBox.jsSource Map URL:renderBookNowBox.js.map 3

Source map error: map is undefined

TypeError: wn.current is null

Uncaught DOMException: Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Error: Minified React error #321;


This is the code that is not displaying:
`  <style>:root {--ldg-bnb-background: #ffffff;--ldg-bnb-border-radius: 0.42em;--ldg-bnb-box-shadow: 0px 24px 54px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);--ldg-bnb-padding: 14px;--ldg-bnb-input-background: #ffffff;--ldg-bnb-button-border-radius: 0px;

--ldg-bnb-color-primary: #6bcdd8; --ldg-bnb-color-primary-lighter:#b5e6ec; --ldg-bnb-color-primary-darker: #36676c; --ldg-bnb-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff; --ldg-component-calendar-cell-selection-bg-color: #6bcdd8; --ldg-component-calendar-cell-selection-color: #ffffff; --ldg-component-calendar-cell-selected-bg-color: #b5e6ec; --ldg-component-calendar-cell-selected-color: #ffffff; --ldg-bnb-font-family: inherit;

}#lodgify-book-now-box {width: 100%;}</style>

data-version="stable" 

I cleared the cache, and deactivated plugins and theme to see if this made any changes, which it didn't. I contacted Lodgify and Elementor but both support teams say they can't help me. Lodgify says the code works from their end.
I have to say I'm no expert in developing and coding. Hope someone can help.
